# Deriving the complex dynamic modulus in a maxwell model

Tags: complex-numbers, stress-strain

In the context of the Maxwell model for viscoelastic materials, how would one derive the [complex dynamic modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_material#Dynamic_modulus)? It is defined as the ratio of the stress to the strain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in this [online pdf document](http://web.mit.edu/course/3/3.11/www/modules/visco.pdf). The Maxwell model can be visualised as a spring and a dashpot. The stress $\sigma$ on the system is the same as the stress on both components of the system and the strain $\epsilon$ is the sum of the strain on the string and the strain on the dashpot. The dynamic response is calculated as
$$\dot{\epsilon} = \dot{\epsilon}_{spring} + \dot{\epsilon}_{dashpot} = \frac{\dot{\sigma}}{k} + \frac{\sigma}{\eta}$$
where $k$ is the stiffness of the spring (from Hooke's law $\sigma = k\epsilon$) and $\eta$ is the viscosity. Define the response timescale or relaxation timescale or Maxwell time as $\tau = \eta/k$. You can now write
$$k\dot{\epsilon} = \dot{\sigma} + \frac{1}{\tau}\sigma$$

In the case of dynamic response the time dependency of the strain and the stress is written as an exponential $\exp{(i\omega t)}$. Plugging this into the previous equation yields
$$k(i\omega)\epsilon_0^*\exp{(i\omega t)} = i\omega \sigma_0^*\exp{(i\omega t)} + \frac{1}{\tau}\sigma_0^*\exp{(i\omega t)}$$
The complex dynamic modulus is then
$$E^* = \frac{\sigma_0^*}{\epsilon_0^*} = \frac{k(i\omega)}{i\omega - \frac{1}{\tau}}$$
In planetary physics, the Maxwell model is often used to describe the interior of planets. In that case $k$ is sometimes written as $\mu_u$, the unrelaxed rigidity and $E^*$ as $\mu$, the complex shear modulus. The Maxwell model then yields
$$\mu = \frac{i\omega \mu_u}{i\omega + \frac{\mu_u}{\eta}}$$